# Does NserviceBus finishes message handling if windows service is stopped?

Tags: nservicebus

I have nservicebus program installed as windows service. 
When I stop windows service, does NserviceBus waits until current message handler is completed?

If the answer is no, then I may do a half of the work, and appear in incorrect state(if my program uses database).

I have done an experiment - created a program that does Thread.Sleep(100 * 1000) when it receives message.
When I stop windows service while message processing, it stops quickly and do not wait 100 seconds. So I assume that the answer is no.

If the answer is yes, please point me to the place in source code, where such stuff occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSB does not wait so the current message will rollback to the queue. All handlers are run in a transaction so there should be no risk to get in an inconsistent state. Assuming that your database is enlisted in the dtc transaction. If not you'll be inconsistent anyway so all bets are off.